# Loading log4j properties from a package in java

Tags: java, properties, log4j

In my java swing application I load log4j properties from a properties file stored in a package in the application and I load that properties file as,

```
try {                            
     PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/log4j.properties");
     logger.info("Starting the system.");                           

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Then I get following error when the application is starts,

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [conf/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:297)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:315)
        at com.bio.ofm.mnu.views.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:70)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [conf/log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.bio.ofm.mnu.views.SplashScreen).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Is this way of loading property file is wrong? please help.

I build a .jar file and run the application using that jar**

Comment: Is your property file stored in the file system or in a JAR file? And in either case, is the path you are using correct? You are using a relative path, that can (and likely will) cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: my properties file is in the jar

Comment: See the answer by Diego, that should work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If conf is the source folder you can use:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("classpath:conf/log4j.properties");
```

else you can try this:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("conf/log4j.properties"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `LogManager` automatically class will look for a file named `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` in the **`classpath`** used for loading the log4j classes. Up to version 1.2.6, log4j would look for only the `log4j.properties` file in the classpath. Since version 1.2.7, log4j looks for both `log4j.properties` and `log4j.xml` in the classpath.

Simply place log4j file in the default package. You should also make sure that the file is in directory  of `.class`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Rachel java library http://rachel.sourceforge.net/ a lot for this kind of stuff

Download the lib and add it to your class path. Then you can use it like so to load any file from a JAR file / package and it also work when using JNLP deployed applications. They have a lot of good tutorials to read on the best way to load your file. I usually like to load them as inputstreams.